# PHP MySQL only displaying one row in table prior to update

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a page to update existing recipe records which are in a MySQL database.  It brings in the dish details which also includes a separate table of ingredients.  However my code only displays one line in the table of ingredients, which I think is the ingredient with the highest ID.  I need it to display all the ingredients, but can't work out what needs changing in my code.  It gives the user the option to edit and add/delete (using JavaScript) rows if required.

I'm quite new to PHP, so my code may not be efficient but it does update the records.  It just won't display all of them in the first instance.

Here's the snippet from my code.  The Connection and $DishID are defined earlier on the page.

```
        <table id="Table" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>#</td>
            <td>IngID</td>
            <td>Volume</td>
            <td>UnitID</td>
            <td>Delete</td>
            <td>Add</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
<?php
    $cdquery="SELECT i.IngID, i.IngName, di.Volume, i.UnitID 
        FROM Ing i
        join DishIng di
        on i.IngID = di.IngID
        Where di.DishID = $DishID";
            $cdresult=mysqli_query($con, $cdquery) or die ("Query to get data from ingredients failed: ".mysqli_error($con));

            while ($cdrow=mysqli_fetch_array($cdresult)) {
        $IngID=$cdrow["IngID"];
        $IngName=$cdrow["IngName"];
        $Volume=$cdrow["Volume"];
        $UnitID=$cdrow["UnitID"];
}
php?>
            <td><input type="text" name="IngID[]" value="<? echo $IngID; ?>"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="IngName[]" value="<? echo $IngName; ?>"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Volume[]" value="<? echo $Volume; ?>"></td>       
            <td><input type="text" name="UnitID[]" value="<? echo $UnitID; ?>"></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="del" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onclick="insRow()"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Once echo mysql_num_rows($cdresult);  and see how many rows its returning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bring your `input insdie the while loop` 
and your `button` outside of `while loop` like this

```
echo '<form>';
while ($cdrow=mysqli_fetch_array($cdresult)) {
        $IngID=$cdrow["IngID"];
        $IngName=$cdrow["IngName"];
        $Volume=$cdrow["Volume"];
        $UnitID=$cdrow["UnitID"];
         ?>
<td><input type="text" name="IngID[]" value="<? echo $IngID; ?>"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="IngName[]" value="<? echo $IngName; ?>"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Volume[]" value="<? echo $Volume; ?>"></td>       
            <td><input type="text" name="UnitID[]" value="<? echo $UnitID; ?>"></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
<?php }?>

<td><input type="button" id="del" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onclick="insRow()"/></td> 
            </form>
```

**Note** `mysqli_` does not automatically secure your application, `bind your value.`

Comment: Thank you, worked a charm.  What do you mean by 'bind your value'?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="Table" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>#</td>
        <td>IngID</td>
        <td>Volume</td>
        <td>UnitID</td>
        <td>Delete</td>
        <td>Add</td>
    </tr>
```

< ?php

```
$DishID = 'put the value here!!!!!!!';
$cdquery="
    SELECT 
        i.IngID,
        i.IngName,
        di.Volume,
        i.UnitID 
    FROM 
        Ing i,
        DishIng di
    WHERE 
        i.IngID = di.IngID
        di.DishID = '".$DishID."'
";

$cdresult = mysqli_query($con, $cdquery) or die ("Query to get data from ingredients failed: ".mysqli_error($con));

$i = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_all($cdresult, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
```

?>

```
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="IngID[]" value="<?php echo $row['IngID']; ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="IngName[]" value="<?php echo $row['IngName']; ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Volume[]" value="<?php echo $row['Volume']; ?>"></td>       
        <td><input type="text" name="UnitID[]" value="<?php echo $row['UnitID']; ?>"></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="del" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"/></td>
        <td><input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onclick="insRow()"/></td>
    </tr>
```

< ?php } ?>